# picture in watermark is not exactly at center

Tags: watermark

As you can see, the Picture location is not in center. What should I do?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics[scale=1]{torang2.jpg}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\usepackage[right=3.1cm,left=3.2cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ptext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some text is in the picture!

It should be maintained that the picture size is as same as document size

Comment: Why not just make the right margin larger (or at least the same size as the left margin)?

Answer (score 1):

As you did not post the picture, I used the example image. The easiest solution for you is to simply add a negative `\hspace` containing the difference between the margins.

Of course I wonder if .1cm difference is really that problem, but here's the modified result (without Persian, because I do not have that font).

[image: negative hspace]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[right=3.1cm,left=3.2cm,top=4cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\hspace*{-.1cm}\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a.pdf}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\lipsum
\end{document}
```